# Filter not registering on first character

Tags: angularjs

I a user list that pops up when a user types @ into a text field. When this happens I want the user list to be filtered for every letter typed after the @ symbol. So if they typed "@s" all usernames starting with an "s" would show. I'm recording the text typed after the @ and assigning it as the text to filter by, but the filter won't act until two characters have been typed. Can someone tell me why this would be happening? Thank you for your help.

HTML/SLIM:

```
/ USER LIST
.user-list.list-group [ng-show="usersShow"]
  a.user.list-group-item [ng-repeat="user in users | filter:formattedUser"]
    strong
      | {{user.username}}
    | {{' : ' + (user | fullName)}}

/ COMMENT FORM
= form_for Comment.new, html: {action: nil, name: 'newCommentForm', 'ng-submit' => 'createComment($event, comment)'} do |f|

   = f.text_field :text, placeholder: 'Add comment...',
  'ng-model' => 'comment.text', 'ng-change' => 'showUserList(comment.text)'
    span.input-group-btn
      button.btn type="submit" Add Comment
```

JS:

```
$scope.showUserList = function(comment) {
  var USERNAME_PATTERN = /(?:^|\s)@\S*$/;
  var comment = comment || '';
  var userMatch = comment.match(USERNAME_PATTERN) || '';

  if(userMatch) {
    $scope.userFormatted = userMatch[0].replace('@', '').trim();
  }

  $scope.usersShow = USERNAME_PATTERN.test(comment);
};
```

Comment: is there any chance you could put this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Jorg sorry for the delay. I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sturoid/hDCjK/) here. The weird thing is that it seems to be working great on the fiddle but on my app it won't start the filter until I type in a second character after the @ symbol. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: In your app, is it firing `showUserList` when typing the @ and just not recognizing the regex or something, or is it only firing after the second character?

Comment: @Jorg I think the regex and everything is working right because on the fiddle it works great, but on the app itself it won't filter anything until the @ and two characters are typed.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you with that as I have nothing really to go on :(

Comment: @Jorg No problem at all. I'm kind of stuck on it for the time being. Thank you for your time though.